# How do I add a toolbar with controls to the DefaultInformationControl?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hover, swt

What I managed to do so far is adding a ToolBarManager for the ToolBar I created, which contains the ToolItem I want to add but nothing is shown when the hover popup based on this DefaultInformationControl is open.
I gave all the ToolItems text and style.

My code is :

```java
public class JavaTextHover implements IJavaEditorTextHover, ITextHoverExtension{
.
.
.
    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
        return new IInformationControlCreator() {
            public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
                ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(parent, SWT.NONE);
                ToolItem itemPush = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
                itemPush.setText("PUSH item");
                ToolItem itemCheck = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.CHECK);
                itemCheck.setText("CHECK item");
                ToolItem itemRadio1 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.RADIO);
                itemRadio1.setText("RADIO item 1");
                ToolItem itemRadio2 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.RADIO);
                itemRadio2.setText("RADIO item 2");
                ToolItem itemSeparator = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
                Text text = new Text(toolBar, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
                text.pack();
                itemSeparator.setWidth(text.getBounds().width);
                itemSeparator.setControl(text);
                final ToolItem itemDropDown = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
                itemDropDown.setText("DROP_DOWN item");
                itemDropDown.setToolTipText("Click here to see a drop down menu ...");
                final Menu menu = new Menu(parent, SWT.POP_UP);
                new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH).setText("Menu item 1");
                new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH).setText("Menu item 2");
                new MenuItem(menu, SWT.SEPARATOR);
                new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH).setText("Menu item 3");
                itemDropDown.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                    if(event.detail == SWT.ARROW) {
                      Rectangle bounds = itemDropDown.getBounds();
                      Point point = toolBar.toDisplay(bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height);
                      menu.setLocation(point);
                      menu.setVisible(true);
                    }
                  }
                });
                Listener selectionListener = new Listener() {
                  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                    ToolItem item = (ToolItem)event.widget;
                    System.out.println(item.getText() + " is selected");
                    if( (item.getStyle() & SWT.RADIO) != 0 || (item.getStyle() & SWT.CHECK) != 0 ) 
                      System.out.println("Selection status: " + item.getSelection());
                  }
                };
                itemPush.addListener(SWT.Selection, selectionListener);
                itemCheck.addListener(SWT.Selection, selectionListener);
                itemRadio1.addListener(SWT.Selection, selectionListener);
                itemRadio2.addListener(SWT.Selection, selectionListener);
                itemDropDown.addListener(SWT.Selection, selectionListener);
                toolBar.pack();
                toolBar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,false));
                ToolBarManager tbm=new ToolBarManager(toolBar);
                System.out.println(tbm.getControl().getChildren().length);
                DefaultInformationControl dic=new DefaultInformationControl(parent, tbm);
                dic.setBackgroundColor(new Color(null, 98,201,145));
                return dic;
            }
        };
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Just add it to the main post

Answer (score 0):

The only example of using the tool bar that I can see in the Eclipse core code does things this way:

```
private static final class PresenterControlCreator extends AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator {

    @Override
    public IInformationControl doCreateInformationControl(Shell parent) {
        ToolBarManager tbm= new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
        NLSHoverControl iControl= new NLSHoverControl(parent, tbm);
        OpenPropertiesFileAction openPropertiesFileAction= new OpenPropertiesFileAction(iControl);
        tbm.add(openPropertiesFileAction);
        tbm.update(true);
        return iControl;
    }
}
```

`NLSHoverControl` extends `DefaultInformationControl`.

So it is adding to the tool bar after creating the DefaultInformationControl and using actions rather than tool items.

```
static class NLSHoverControl extends DefaultInformationControl implements IInformationControlExtension2 {

    /**
     * The NLS control input.
     */
    private NLSHoverControlInput fInput;

    /**
     * Creates a resizable NLS hover control with the given shell as parent.
     * 
     * @param parent the parent shell
     * @param tbm the toolbar manager or <code>null</code> if toolbar is not desired
     */
    public NLSHoverControl(Shell parent, ToolBarManager tbm) {
        super(parent, tbm);

    }

    /**
     * Creates an NLS hover control with the given shell as parent.
     * 
     * @param parent the parent shell
     * @param tooltipAffordanceString the text to be used in the status field or
     *            <code>null</code> to hide the status field
     */
    public NLSHoverControl(Shell parent, String tooltipAffordanceString) {
        super(parent, tooltipAffordanceString);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} This control can handle {@link NLSStringHover.NLSHoverControlInput}.
     */
    public void setInput(Object input) {
        Assert.isLegal(input instanceof NLSHoverControlInput);

        NLSHoverControlInput info= (NLSHoverControlInput)input;
        setInformation(info.fInformation);
        fInput= info;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the control input.
     * 
     * @return the control input
     */
    public NLSHoverControlInput getInput() {
        return fInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find any info about the NlsHoverControl can you give a link or something, or maybe  you got confused with the NLSStringHover?

Comment: No, it is an inner class declared inside `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.NLSStringHover`

Comment: How do I use/access  it or import it to my project ? Or should I just create a class with the code you sent me?

Comment: You can't use it. So either create your own copy, or just use DefaultInformationControl since it doesn't look like it does anything that would change the toolbar.